# How to convert attributes into labels in Prometheus jmx-exporter?

Tags: prometheus, jmx-exporter

I have a metric with a lot of attributes and I want to export that into prometheus with the labels.

For instance I have a object with objectname containing type=status, connector=something,task=something but it has attributes WorkerId, Trace and State.

If I use a rule like this, it does not work.

```
pattern: "com.connect.task<type=status, connector=([^:]+), task=([^:]+,WorkerId: ([^:]+),Trace: ([^:]+))><>State: ([^:]+)"
name: "com_connect_connector_task_status"
value: 1
labels:
  connector: $1
  task: $2
  status: $3
  worker_id: $4
  trace: $5
```

How are users supposed to get attributes into labels?

Comment: Are you sure everything else is OK? Can you export the value without the labels?